# Can't clone hosted git repository from linode server

Tags: git, ubuntu, gitlab, linode

I recently set up a linode server (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) to host a webapp for a university project. 
If I want to clone our project repository (it is hosted by my university) I get the following errors:

**Cloning over https:**

```
yannic@flask-blog-server:~$ sudo git clone git@ops.hs-kempten.de:swp/vorlage.git
Cloning into 'vorlage'...                   [This step always took 2 or 3 minutes]
ssh: connect to host ops.hs-kempten.de port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**Cloning over ssh:**

```
yannic@flask-blog-server:~$ git clone https://ops.hs-kempten.de/swp/vorlage.git
Cloning into 'vorlage'...                 [Again this step took 2 or 3 minutes]
fatal: unable to access 'https://ops.hs-kempten.de/swp/vorlage.git/': Failed to connect to ops.hs-kempten.de port 443: Connection timed out
```

I was able to clone said repository from my Windows PC, from my Raspberry and from the Windows Subsystem for Linux. 
I was also able to clone repositorys hosted on gitlab.com and github.com from my linode server.

Comment: `ops.hs-kempten.de` is not accessible for me and not only for me: https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/ops.hs-kempten.de. You said "*I was able to clone said repository from my PC*" — are you in the same network with the host? Could it be available for your but not for anyone outside your network?

Comment: No I am not in the same network, I did it from my home and I do not have a VPN tunnel to my university enabled.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to be an issue with the permissions that are set up over at either `ops.hs-kempten.de` or permissions set up on your Linode.  I created a new Linode and installed git.  I then chose a random repository to test the cloning process.  When cloning by SSH I got an error regarding the need for public key.[1]  This was the expected result and there was no waiting for 2 - 3 minutes for the error.  Next, I tested the same repository with HTTPS and that cloned successfully with no problems. [2]

I also tested with your repository via SSH and HTTPS and got the same results as you did. [3] [4]

Why not create a new Linode, install git, and then attempt to clone your repository and a random repo?  Again, I suspect there is some permissions error so be sure to double check those at both your Linode's end or your git server's end.

Good luck!

[1]

```sh
[root@llin62 ~]# git clone git@github.com:elunez/eladmin.git
Cloning into 'eladmin'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.112.3' to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

[2]

```sh
[root@llin62 ~]# git clone https://github.com/elunez/eladmin.git
Cloning into 'eladmin'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 216, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (216/216), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (128/128), done.
remote: Total 8138 (delta 70), reused 167 (delta 50), pack-reused 7922
Receiving objects: 100% (8138/8138), 6.30 MiB | 16.12 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3931/3931), done.
```

[3]

```sh
[root@llin62 ~]# git clone git@ops.hs-kempten.de:swp/vorlage.git
Cloning into 'vorlage'...
ssh: connect to host ops.hs-kempten.de port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

[4]

```sh
[root@llin62 ~]# git clone https://ops.hs-kempten.de/swp/vorlage.git
Cloning into 'vorlage'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://ops.hs-kempten.de/swp/vorlage.git/': Failed to connect to ops.hs-kempten.de port 443: Connection timed out
```